# Use Heroku DB into Engine Yard

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, postgresql, heroku, engineyard

I am using postgresql database for my Heroku Application.

I have very large database on AmazonAws as heroku not providing the Postgresql Database.

Now my client want to switch to EngineYard from Heroku.

Can i use same database (w/o taking backup and then reload) for my application on the EngineYard?

```
If YES
```

How can i use or steps for using the Existing AmazonAws Database with the new EngineYard Application.

Answer (score 1):

You can, but only if you are using a dedicated database. From the [Heroku database FAQ](http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/database#frequently-asked-questions)

> Shared Database
>
> No, connecting to your database from machines outside of Heroku is not
>   supported. We recommend that you encapsulate data access in an API to
>   manipulate it.
>
> Dedicated Database
>
> It's possible to connect to our dedicated databases using our
>   pg:ingress feature. Please see using the PG console for more
>   information.

The database connection string is available in the `DATABASE_URL` config. You can run

```
$ heroku config --long
```

to view it. However, it won't probably work if you use a shared database because it seems connection is restricted to the Heroku net.

Answer (score 0):

Surely this is just a case of getting the correct connection credentials for the DB regardless of where it's hosted?

For instance, if the DB is on Heroku, then ENV['DATABASE_URL'] give you everything you need.  All these details then go in your database.yml as normal (assuming you're using ActiveRecord)

For the record, Heroku do provide Postgres and it's part of their core business.